# Difference between NP-hard and NP-complete

Tags: definition, computational-complexity, np-complete

I am struggling to tell the difference between the definitions of NP-hard and NP-complete problems. I know that NP-complete problems are NP-hard, so this tells me that $$\text{$P_1$ polynomially transforms to $P_2$}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{$P_1$ polynomially reduces to $P_2$},$$
but seeing why this is true is not obvious from the definitions.

These were the definitions given:

> Let $P_1=(X_1,Y_1)$ and $P_2=(X_2,Y_2)$ be two decision problems—i.e. $X_i$ is a set of all instances and $Y_i$ is the set of "yes instances". Let $g\colon X_2\to \{0,1\}$ be such that $g(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in Y_2$.
>
> - We say that $P_1$ *polynomially reduces* to $P_2$ if there exists a polynomial time oracle algorithm for $P_1$ using $g$.
> - We say that $P_1$ *polynomially transforms to $P_2$* if there exists a function $f\colon X_1\to X_2$ computable in polynomial time such that $f(x_1)\in Y_2$ for all $x_1\in Y_1$ and $f(x_1)\in X_2-Y_2$ for all $x_1\in X_1-Y_1$.
>
> Then, a problem is
>
> - *NP-hard* if all problems in NP polynomially reduce to it; and
> - *NP-complete* if all problems in NP polynomially transform to it.

What is the difference between polynomial reduction and polynomial transformation? I am unsure what the definition of polynomial reduction means exactly; I had thought the "polynomial time oracle algorithm" would be defined in the same way that $f$ was.

Comment: NP-complete problems are required to be in NP themselves; NP-hard problems aren't. (E.g., the halting problem is NP-hard but not NP-complete).

Comment: The meaning of "NP-hard" you quote (based on Turing reductions rather than the usual polynomial-time many-one reductions) is not standard in my experience -- where have you got that from?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is given as definition 15.34 in Bernhard Korte and Jens Vygen's "Combinatorial Optimization Theory and Algorithms" third edition.

Comment: Not sure to get the "$P_1$ polynomially reduces to $P_2$" definition, are we allowed to read polynomially many values of $g$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I am not sure what the author means by "using $g$", since I thought that that would be the same as the definition of polynomial transformation. Here is the excerpt from the book where it is introduced (different notation) http://i.imgur.com/Sp5cMad.png

Comment: Their "polynomially reduces" means [polynomially Turing-reduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Types_of_reduction), and their "polynomially transforms" ​ means [polynomially many-one reduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Types_of_reduction). ​ In standard terminology, reduce/reduces/reduction/reductions $\hspace{.11 in}$ refer to many-one reductions. ​ Should my answer use their terminology or standard terminology? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Oh that's good to know, thanks. Standard terminology would be more useful for the site's audience I think; it would be worth mentioning in the answer that the question uses different terminology, though.

Comment: (I should've put "by default" between "reduction/reductions" and "refer". ​ I didn't mean to suggest that the concept of polynomial Turing reduction is rarely used.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their "polynomially reduces" means [polynomially Turing-reduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Types_of_reduction), and

their "polynomially transforms" ​ means [polynomially many-one reduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Types_of_reduction).

In standard terminology, which I'll use for this answer,

reduce/reduces/reduction/reductions by default 
refer to many-one.

"using $g$" ​ / ​ "Turing reduction" ​ ​ ​ mean the same thing, and are defined via [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine).

Many-one reductions are equivalent to the special case in which [[the machine always queries

the oracle exactly once] and [the machine always gives the same output as the oracle]].

To compute $\hspace{.04 in}f\hspace{-0.03 in}$, replace "enter the ask state" with "output the contents of the oracle tape".

Now, for $\;\;\;$ many-one reduction $\: \implies \:$ Turing reduction $\;\;\;$:

You have an oracle for $g$ and can evaluate $\hspace{.03 in}f\hspace{-0.03 in}$, so just output $g(\hspace{.05 in}f(x))$. $\:$ It's that simple.

Their definition of NP-hard is correct;

[different notions of reduction yield different definitions of NP-hard](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/138/6973).

Their definition of NP-complete is missing an important part:

L is NP-complete $\;\; \iff \;\;$ L is NP-hard ​ **and** ​ L is in NP $\;\;\;\;\;$ .